# jquery use of $.each with jq output array to make listbox from json output

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I used jq to extract an array of json key:value pairs into an array, but I a not sure how to then use it to populate an html select listbox.

If I go through hoopla of adding stuff to the jq output I can read it, but maybe the answer is in getting the jq output to be accurate json that is in a non-anonymous array.  I am just not sure how to do this.

jq is outputting something like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 82247683,
    "name": "project1"
  },
  {
    "id": 7700483,
    "name": "project2"
  }
]
```

What works with jquery $.each is if the format was instead like:

```
{"project": [
  {
    "id": 82247683,
    "name": "project1"
  },
  {
    "id": 7700483,
    "name": "project2"
  }
]}
```

At the moment I am literally tacking on the first line and the last line to get this data to be json data again and to get it to work with getJSON.

The $.each loop I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $select = $('#project');
    $.getJSON('projects.json', function(data) {
        $select.html('');
        $.each(data.project, function(key,val) {
          $select.append('<option id="'+val.id+'">'+val.name+'</options>');
        })
    });
</script>
```

Because of the getJSON use plus using $.each(data.project) I need to tack on the array name plus the other elements.

I would appreciate from you information on either using jq to get the right json out or whatever modifications I would need to do with the getJSON + $.each to get it to work with the jq output as it comes out now.  Also, does getJSON in this scenario even need the array to be non-anonymous?

The end result should be the populated listbox.

Comment: $.each doesn't care what of those two formats you use, as long as you give it what you want it to iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id": 82247683,
    "name": "project1"
  },
  {
    "id": 7700483,
    "name": "project2"
  }
];

var data2 = {
  "project": [
    {
      "id": 82247683,
      "name": "project1"
    },
    {
      "id": 7700483,
      "name": "project2"
    }
  ]
};

console.log('data');
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  console.log('<option id="'+val.id+'">'+val.name+'</options>');
});

console.log('data2');
$.each(data2.project, function(key, val) {
  console.log('<option id="'+val.id+'">'+val.name+'</options>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Either format will work. Notice that for `data` you do not use `data.project`.

So for your example:

```
$.getJSON('projects.json', function(data) {
  $select.html('');
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $select.append('<option id="'+val.id+'">'+val.name+'</options>');
  })
});
```

Comment: I am not sure how to translate this into my code though.  I am using $.getJSON whereas you have two variables set not defined by $.getJSON.  I tried something like var data = $.getJSON('projects.json');  That does not work though.  Your codes does show though that $.each  could be used with anonymous array and named array.

Comment: I tried instead to do something like var data; $.getJSON('projects.json', function(json) { data = json; } and then to use that data variable, but the issue I think is that unless I tack on the {"project": [ and the ]} at the end the data is not seen as legitimate json.

Comment: You just need to change `data.project` to `data`. I just added it to my answer explicitly.